# Type Error: Object(...) is not a Function React js

Tags: reactjs

despite of having higher react and react-dom version im facing the issue

```
const {login,setLogin} = useState({email:"",password:""});
const history = useHistory(); <--- facing error at this line (all the imports done perfectly)
```

Comment: the return of ```useState``` is tuple so ```const [login,setLogin]= useState({email:"",password:""});```

Answer (score 1):

useState hook returns an Array so you need to do array destructuring instead of object destructuring

```
const [login,setLogin] = useState({email:"",password:""});
```